# Advice for career change to crypto?

Tags: number-theory

I'll keep this brief. I'm a maths teacher in the UK looking at a career change into cryptography, especially the mathematical side of it - I've studied analytic number theory recently and really enjoyed it. Unfortunately I have essentially 0 coding experience, so what would be a good place to start if I'd like to start looking at grad schemes soon? Many thanks.
(sorry, didn't know what tag to use so I put number theory as that's what I've been studying)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a place for this but, You should try learning statistics and probability first  if you haven't already and then learn about computational complexity and complexity classes. Cryptography often deals with questions like "can this problem be solved efficiently" rather than "Does this have a solution?" whose answer in majority cases will certainly be yes.

Comment: Yes, this is off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I recommend [academia-SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) to discuss the career change aspect, and if you plan teaching crypto, first learning it from a reference used in modern courses. One that comes to mind is Jonathan Katz and Yehuda Lindell's [_Introduction to Modern Cryptography_](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/imc.html).

Comment: But keep in mind that everybody calls symmetric cryptography **secret** key cryptography, not private key cryptography as the key is not kept private but shared between the participants, and that the other option is **public/private** key cryptography where the key **is** kept private (and secret by extension). Just to avoid (even more) confusion.

Comment: You can now talk in our [chat], Welcome!